# How to block unwanted image size changes in Word365

Tags: ms-word

I write a lot of texts in Word and I use images specified as fields of type INCLUDEPICTURE in my texts, so that I can easily edit the referenced image file with this image if needed. But when I need to update the links in a block of text, Word will “initiatively” resize the images in the selected block(usually making them significantly larger), completely throwing off the layout. Earlier versions of Word (i.e., from version 2.0 to version 2013) didn't do such screw-ups. I have not been able to find out how to turn off this "initiative" of it. Can anyone give any advice?

When I update the selected block of text (or the entire document text) by pressing the F9 key, I expect all references of type REF, PAGEREF, etc. to be updated, but I don't expect the sizes of referenced images in fields of type INCLUDEPICTURE to change.

Comment: Simple: Insert the field code into a table cell having a fixed height and width. The image will be constrained to fit the space available, at the correct aspect ratio for the image. To set the fixed:
• row height, use Table Tools>Layout>Properties>Row>Specify Height>Exactly.
• column width, uncheck the 'automatically resize to fit contents' option under Table Tools>Layout>Properties>Table>Options. Then set the preferred column width under Table Tools>Layout>Properties>Columns.
Set the cell margins to 0 all round and format the cell paragraph with 0 before/after spacing. No code required.